# codeigniter - send email not working for some email clients

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

My app is to send emails to my office staff email addresses.
It is working fine with @gmail.com and @yahoo.com email addresses. But it is not working for my office email which is what I want to do.

this is my code.

```
    $this->load->library('email');

    $this->email->from('abc@myoffice.com','My Name');
    $this->email->to('pqrs@myoffice.com,aaaa@yahoo.com'); 
    $this->email->cc('xyz@myoffice.com,bbbb@gmail.com,hijk@myoffice.com'); 
    $this->email->subject('My Subject');
    $this->email->message('My Message');    

    $this->email->send();
```

I get the email to yahoo and gmail but no email received to my office address. Can any one say what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: have you check your spam, may be possible you will get your office email in your spam.

Comment: Might be something on your office's mail server

Comment: read the [email](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html) documentation. You might be missing something

Comment: @Zeeshan yes I did the spam. But nothing there.

Comment: @DamienPirsy Ok thanx. I'll check with them

Comment: @raheelshan No I checked all. Nothing missing as far as I know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try configuring `email.php` by adding your office's smtp host, port, username and password. Or you can initialize it while loading email library.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'SMTPserver';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'SMTP Username';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'SMTP Password';
$config['smtp_port'] = 'SMTP Port';

$this->email->initialize($config);
```

Comment: Thanx. I figure it out :)